# The onSubmit action is not triggered when the axis is vertical in the TextField

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, textfield, ios16

In the multiline TextField I want to play with the focus for that I have to receive the onSubmit action. In the following code example when the axis is vertical in the TextField I don't receive the event.

Is there any way to get it?

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestingView: View {

    @State var optionA = ""
    @State var optionB = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Group() {
                    CustomRow(title: "Option A", value: $optionA)
                    CustomRow(title: "Option B", value: $optionB)
                }
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            }
            .navigationTitle("Testing View")
            .padding(.zero)
        }
    }
}

struct CustomRow: View {

    var title: String = ""
    @Binding var value: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(title)
                .font(.system(.headline, design: .rounded))
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            TextField("", text: $value, axis: .vertical)
                .border(.gray, width: 2)
                .padding(4)
                .font(.system(.body, design: .rounded))
                .frame(minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 200)
                .onSubmit {
                    print("Submit action")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct TestingView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TestingView()
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tried your code using Xcode 14.3 & I can see "Submit action" printed. Are you able to provide some additional information?

Comment: @Timmy I use Xcode 14.3. Did you see "Submit action text" when pressing the return key?. For me the event onSubmit is never called.